# Partial Derivative and inverses

Tags: calculus

I have $s^2 = r^2 \sin^2\theta$. I want to compute $\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial s}$. My approach was

$s = r \sin \theta$

$\arcsin \dfrac{s}{r} = \theta$

$\dfrac{1}{r \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{s^2}{r^2}}} = \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial s}$.

$\dfrac{1}{r \cos \theta} = \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial s}$.

My book's answer however is $\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial s} = \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r}$.

Comment: Your calculation is fine, and your book has a typo.

Comment: This is  from my partial differential equations book and the result $\frac{\cos \theta}{r}$ gives the correct solution for invariance in 3 dimensions so it must be a misunderstanding I'm having of the derivation.

Comment: If you pick a non-zero real number r and graph $\arcsin\frac{s}{r}$, you will observe that rate of change becomes undefined at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$. This supports your calculation because the partial derivative becomes 1/rcos(pi/2) = $\frac10$.